# t-sql - combine table metadata and column values

Tags: generics, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to write a query in T-SQL like this:

```
select *
from
(select t.name tablename
from sys.columns c join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name like 'column1'
) candidatetables
where tablename.column2 = 3
```

The problem is in the last filter. I get this error "The multi-part identifier "tablename.column2" could not be bound.".

This query should get the tables that have the column "column1" in their schema and for which the value of the column named "column2", which is sure to exists in all the tables, equals 3. Is it possible to write the last filter in a different manner in order to accomplish this?

Comment: So you want the output of your query to be a list of table names or do you want the data in the tables?

Comment: First i want to get the tables that have column1 in their schema and a given value for their column2. Then i want to query these tables. Thought of it as a two-step process.

Comment: Say I have tables 
    T1(column1, column2), T2(column1, column2), T3(column1, column2), T4(column4, column2)

Furthermore, assume T1.column2 = 3, T2.column2 = 1000, T3.column2 = 3.

First i would get T1, T2 and T3, as they all have column1 in their schema. But in the next step, I want to obtain tables T1 and T3, because the value of the field column2 for these tables is 3. 

And in the end I'd like to query other fields from these tables.

Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have does not query the tables you find. You have to build a query dynamically that queries each table you find and then combines the result using `union all`.

Try this:

```
declare @Col2Value int = 3
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

select @SQL = 
(
  select 'union all '+
         'select top(1) '''+t.name+''' as TableName '+
         'from '+quotename(t.name)+' '+
         'where Column2 = '+cast(@Col2Value as nvarchar(10))+' '
  from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t
      on c.object_id = t.object_id
  where c.name = 'Column1'
  for xml path(''), type
).value('substring(./text()[1], 11)', 'nvarchar(max)')

exec (@SQL)
```

The code above will build and execute a query that looks something like this:

```
select top(1) 'Table1' as TableName
from [Table1]
where Column2 = 3
union all
select top(1) 'Table2' as TableName
from [Table2] 
where Column2 = 3
union all 
select top(1) 'Table3' as TableName
from [Table3] 
where Column2 = 3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcbf6/1/0)

Comment: this is nice & working. thanks.
two further questions. 1. why is it necessary to transform the result of the query to xml? 
2. if i have two dynamic SQLs (1 and 2) like the one in the example, which filter different tables, is it possible to write a query that joins a table from SQL1 with a table from SQL2 and selects some data from those tables?

Comment: The XML stuff is string a concatenate trick used to build one string from multiple rows. For the second part I don't understand what you want. Please update your question or ask a new question. Most likely you have to use the result from this command to build a new dynamic SQL query that does what you want.

Comment: I did what I wanted to. 
I'd read about the for xml, but i was wondering whether other alternatives existed. Thanks

Comment: @user1744925 Another option would be to use a cursor to loop over the rows and build the dynamic SQL in the loop instead.